# GET запрос с параметром

Tags: java, spring, rest, get, boot

Всем привет, буду благодарен за любой совет. В общем, мне нужно отправить get запрос с параметром на внешний rest api. Вот код контроллера:

```
@GetMapping("/add/{value}")
  public ResponseEntity add(@PathVariable(value = "value") String value) {
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForEntity("https://bhub.ru/add/{value}", String.class, "value");
    } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("504 Gateway Time-out. The server didn't respond in time.");

    }
}
```

Проблема такая, когда я выполняю запрос через инсомнию, в БД попадает только uriVariable "value", и так вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы в БД добавлялись строки из гет запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру так:

```
UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://bhub.ru/add/{value}")
            .buildAndExpand(value);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri.toString(), String.class);
```

Примеры для `UriComponents` тут: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder

Или так:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("value", value);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://bhub.ru/add/{value}", String.class, params);
```

Вот еще примеры: https://www.programmersought.com/article/17133006211/